# How to use eval with if else?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

[image]

I have two product pages. If multipleProduct is `false`, it must redirect to ProductDetails-1.aspx, otherwise it must be redirect ProductDetails-2.aspx page.

I got ***Compilation Error:<% else***

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      if <%# Eval("MultipleProduct").ToString() == "No")
       {%>
         <li>
           <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;
           <a href="ProductDetails-1.aspx?ProductID=<%# Eval("ID").ToString()%>" /><%# Eval("ProductName").ToString() %></a>
         </li>
    <% }%> 
    <% else
       { %>
         <li>
           <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;
           <a href="ProductDetails-2.aspx?ProductID=<%# Eval("ID").ToString()%>" /><%# Eval("ProductName").ToString() %></a>
         </li>
       <%} %>                                      
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Compilation Error: <% else

Comment: Check round brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little messy, try another approach, more readable, less duplicate code and less prone to error, creating a method in your code behind

Create a protected method in your aspx class to get the url for the product.

```
protected string GetProductUrl(string multipleProduct, int ID)
{
   string url = multipleProduct == "No" ? "ProductDetails-1.aspx" : "ProductDetails-2.aspx";

   return url + "?ProductID=" + ID; 
}
```

And in your aspx file replace your code with the next.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <li>
             <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;
             <a href="<%# GetProductUrl(Eval("MultipleProduct").ToString(), (int) Eval("ID")) %>" >
                  <%# Eval("ProductName").ToString() %>
            </a>
         </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: i got error: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'MultipleProduct'.

Comment: <a href="<%# GetProductUrl((bool)Eval("MultipleProduct"), (int) Eval("ID")) %>" >

Comment: in database, MultipleProduct nvarchar (100)

Comment: @Shkupjane updated code for MultipleProduct as string. But is not a good idea use a string too store a bool value. The DataBinding error, problably it's caused because your data source is not returning MultipleProduct Column from database.

Comment: u mean, in database i must use bit for MultipleProduct?

Comment: @Shkupjane Yes, if it only contains true or false, the column type must be bit.

Comment: ok but i must change all table so i want to use string. can u change the code with string?? plss

Comment: If I were you I would change to bit, sooner or later you will get problems for not using the right column type. If not Read my first comment "updated code for MultipleProduct as string. ...."

Comment: i updated code for MultipleProduct as string but i got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: I think that there is something wrong in your code. Be sure, that in the GetProductUrl signature MultipleProduct var is declared as string like in my example.